# OrderBy on Range Coulmn(type string)Numerically BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have BQ table which has range column. Values are like`(0-50, 100-150, 200-250,1000-1200, >=400)`.

when I am doing orderBy on this column I am getting it Lexicographic order like `(0-50,100-150,1000-1200,200-250,>=400)`

But I want it to orderBy numerically like`(0-50,100-150, 200-250, >=400, 1000-1200).`
Could someone please help me how to create query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use approach as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with data as (
  select '0-50' range_col union all
  select '100-150' union all
  select '200-250' union all
  select '1000-1200' union all
  select '>=400' 
)
select *
from data
order by cast(regexp_extract(range_col, r'\b(\d+)\b') as int64)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Mikhail, Thanks for your solution. It works for me but one edge case it is not working. for (100-150, <0, 0-50) order should be (<0 ,0-50, 100-150) but I am getting (0-50,<0, 100-150).

Comment: just add `, regexp_extract(range_col, r'^<') desc desc` to the end of `order by` list